# How to find the moovweb template used?

Tags: moovweb

I created a moovweb project  in

http://console.moovweb.com. Is there a way to know the template which I would have selected during the project creation. As I was testing with all templates I don't remember which one I have chosen.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know the templates are not that different. They come out of the box with different styles and 3rd party frameworks, but all that is pretty easily configured. I don't believe you can currently lookup which template you chose, but you should be able to tell based on these differences:

- "base" will have no device detection and leave desktop styles alone
- "mobile" will have device detection and remove desktop styles
- "mobile scaffold" will have a starter style guide and some example html for mobile at the top of the body
- the other frameworks all have 3rd party plugins like foundation or jQuery mobile or are specific to tablet, so you should be able to tell.

Comment: Moovweb allows great flexibility in how you configure your projects. These templates evolved out of how many Moovweb developers work with projects, but you can include libraries and change the way you manage your Tritium scripts - as long as main.ts exists, because that's the first file that gets executed by the Moovweb SDK.

Comment: I've seen people work around this problem by adding the template they started with in the 'Notes' field of their project right after they generate it... so you could do this for future projects :)